# Two circles and parallelogram collinearity problem

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

> $G$ is a point inside a parallelogram $ABCD$.
>
> $(C)$ is a circle passing through $A$ and $G$ meeting sides $[AB]$ and $[AD]$ in $E$ and $F$ respectively.
>
> Line $(EG)$ meets side $[CD]$ in $I$ and lines $(FG)$ meets side $[BC]$ in $H$.
>
> The circumcircle of $\triangle HGI$ meets $(C)$ again in $M$. ($M \ne G$).
>
> Prove that $M$ lies on the diagonal $[AC]$.

[image: Diagram of problem]

I tried using angles but failed so far in proving that $\angle AMC$ is $180$.

The proof is possible if we prove beforehand that $C$ is concyclic with $H$ $G$ and $I$.

Comment: How did you try using angles? You can [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3541276/edit) your post and add in this detail and people will be more willing to help as they can see you have put in some effort

Comment: I think it would be easy if $C$ was concyclic with $H$, $G$, $I$ which seems to be the case

Comment: As suggested you could note, at that purpose, that $\angle FAE$ and $\angle FGE$ are supplementary, which makes $\angle HCI$ and $\angle HGI$ supplementary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $G, I, C, H$ are concyclic. To see this, note that 
$$\angle HGI+\angle DCB=\angle EGF+\angle BAD=180^\circ$$
since $A, E, G, F$ are concyclic. Thus, we have $G, M, C, I$ are concyclic, and so
$$\angle AMG+\angle GMC=\angle AEG+(180^\circ-\angle GIC)=180^\circ,$$
where the last equality uses the fact that $\angle AEG=\angle GIC$ (as $AB$ and $DC$ are parallel).